# Monodromy of "complex Schwarz-Christoffel maps

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let:

--  $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be $n$ distinct points on the complex plane $\mathbb C$.

--  $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ be $n$ real numbers.

Consider the map 
$$ z\mapsto u(z)=\int^z \frac{1}{(x-x_1)^{r_1}\cdots (x-x_n)^{r_n}} d\xi $$

It defines a multivalued holomorphic function on $\mathbb C\setminus (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$

**Question: what is the monodromy of this map?**

Remark: when the $x_i$'s are real and if the $r_i$'s verify $\sum_i r_i=2$, the map $u$ is nothing but a classical Schwarz-Chritoffel map that maps conformally  the upper half-plane onto a closed $n$-gon.

In this classical case, it is well known that the monodromy is affine. But I have been unable to find any reference where the monodromy of $u$ is explicited.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: +1. However, the function is not well defined on $\mathbb{C}$ minus a set of points. You have to choose branches of logarithms at each point or only consider it as a function on the upper halfplane. Can you elaborate what you mean by "the monodromy is affine" and how this conclusion arises (only for the sake of my education;)?

Comment: As said just before the Question, $z\mapsto u(z)$ is ${\bf multivalued}$ on the complement of the union of the $z_i$'s, noted by $U$.

Let $z_0$ be a point distinct with $z_0\neq z_i$ for every $i$. 
For any loop $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow U$ centered at $z_0$ (ie. \gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=z_0$), the monodromy $\mathcal M_{\gamma} u$ is the germ at $z_0$ obtained by analytic continuation of the initial  determinantion of $u$  at $z_0$. Affine monodromy  means $\mathcal M_{\gamma}u=a_{\gamma} u+b_{\gamma}$ with $a_{\gamma},b_{\gamma}\in 
\mathbb C$




Comment: Computation of the local monodromies (up to conjugation) for the small loops around points $x_i$, is a nice undergraduate complex analysis exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monodromy is affine in the general case. It is generated by finitely many elliptic transformations of the form $az+b$. Proof: your function satisfies the differential
equation $u^{\prime\prime}=Ru',$ where $R$ is rational. The general solution of this equation
is obtained from a particular solution by the formula $au+b$.

Computing this monodromy explicitly is as difficult as in
the classical case: you need to compute the integrals of your $u$ from $x_j$ to $x_k$.